# macOS like Expose/ Mission Control on Ubuntu Budgie 20.04

Tags: desktop-environments, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

I recently installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 and was wondering if there is something similar to macOS' Mission Control where you can see every open window and can also access the dock.

The only example that came close was a YouTube video from 2007: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CC4PGEDyRIY (0:10 - 0:17)

I hope some of you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

The standard Ubuntu edition, which uses the Gnome Shell desktop, includes the Activities Overview. This shows you miniatures of all windows of the desktop, the dock, and to the right, the different workspaces that are in use. Clicking "Activities" in the top left corner or pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key quickly brings you to that central overview.

Comment: Yeah, it's a correct answer to the original question (-title). Sorry for changing the title, but in the body, he mentioned using Budgie.

Comment: Indeed, I did not realize this question would be limited to Budgie - there is a link to a video with Compiz showing such a feature.

Comment: FWIW: I run Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my oldie MacBook Pro, from 2011! A tap on the `command` key (same as "Super"??) gives me something very much like the "Mission Control" view in macOS.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu Budgie, we have **Window Previews**.

[image]

You can activate- or gracefully close a window from it.

To start using it: Budgie Menu > Previews Control:

[image]

#### Using it

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> (show windows of all applications) or <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> (show windows of currently active application).

*Alternatively*

Set a hotcorner to call Previews: Budgie Desktop Settings > Panel > Applets, add Hotcorners and make its settings:

[image]